# Remap function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

I have below code where I need to remap(redefine) C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS.

```
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    execute_this();

    pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;

    pPointerToFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I need to redefine `C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS` is, `C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS` is some location in FLASH memory where address of some other function is stored. Since I don't have FLASH, I want to redefine C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS to some address in RAM. For any reason I Shouldn't have to change the line: `pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;`

I've tried below code to do this, this compiles however run-time error occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Testing_pOP_Start(void)
{
    printf("Inside");
    return;
}

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

#define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS (ptemp)

void (*pPointerToFunc)(void);

unsigned long ptemp;

void execute_this(void)
{
    ptemp = (unsigned long)(&Testing_pOP_Start);
}


int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    execute_this();

    pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;

    pPointerToFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me find out what is wrong and how do I achieve this.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Would you tell me how this line compiles: `pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;`... Have you typo'd `(void (*)())` to `(void*)`?

Comment: did you try debugging you code to see where it crashes?

Comment: @inavda I'm using online compiler "IDEONE". The error i get is: Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0s 9288KB

Comment: @Ruks C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS is a value, which is type casted to (uint32_t) pointer. and then dereference the pointer to get value at location C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS, an then convert this to function pointer. This is what i undersatnd

Comment: @MSharathHegde You have a wrong idea about `void*`, it is **not a function pointer**... `void (*)()` is...

Comment: @tod I'm using an online compiler. Would it be possible to debug? I'm Sure it is crashing at line "pPointerToFunc();" Link: https://ideone.com/Z8MmSS

Comment: Then, may be you are messing up with memory... it is not easy to help you without having the better picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @tod I don't want to change the line -- "pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;"  ..and I should be able to call Testing_pOP_Start() using pPointerToFunc. I don't know how do i define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS to achieve what i need.

Comment: @Ruks Can you tell me what does this line `pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;`?

Comment: well, what do you want to achieve in this line?

Comment: what is this line doing? `void (*pPointerToFunc)(void);`

Comment: @tod declaration of pPointerToFunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn how to use a debugger.

I just run your code under a debugger, and the error was immediately evident: after the call to `execute_this`, the values of `ptemp` and `pPointerToFunc` were different.

I then realized that `C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS` was not directly the address of a function, but the address of a pointer to a function (1 more indirection level).

The fix was then evident:

```
#define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS (&ptemp)
```

That's all...

---

*I'm using an online compiler* is not a valid reason not to learn to use a debugger. You can find free compilers around, and a debugger is an essential tool.

Comment: Only changing `#define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS (&ptemp)` should fix the issue right? For me still it sin't working (https://ideone.com/PtUj75). Can you post the full code that worked for you?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta I'm going to install a compiler soon. Currently i'm confined to use only online compiler. The solution is still not working for me though I've made the changes. Link to code: https://ideone.com/82SbQx

Comment: @tod  this code _can't_ work if `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(uint32_t)`

Comment: @ReAl I checked `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(uint32_t)` sizeof(void*) is 8 and sizeof(uint32_t) is 4. that is why I defined ptemp as `unsigned long`

Comment: @MSharathHegde some time ago I updated my answer and especially pointed to this problem. Use 32 bit compiler (compiler mode) if you want to keep `(void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;` as is.

Comment: @ReAl, Serge Ballesta I tried a different online compiler and it worked. This helped a lot, thanks for spending time on this.

Answer (score 1):

> `C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS` is some location in FLASH memory

So that, `C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS` is an *address* in flash memory.

But `#define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS (ptemp)` reads *value* stored in `ptemp`.

You need one of this two changes.
Get *address* of `ptemp` (but it was casted to another type, `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned long`, type must be the same and sufficient to store address, use `intptr_t`).

```
#define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS (&ptemp)
...
pPointerToFunc = (void *)*C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;
```

or read and cast the value itself

```
#define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS (ptemp)
...
pPointerToFunc = (void *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;
```

**Update:**

> Whatever I do I must not change this line -- 
>   `pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;`
>   Could this be possible?

Use the first approash but `ptemp` *must* be `uint32_t` — the same type as cast in the (fixed) line.

```
#define C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS (&ptemp)
...
uint32_t long ptemp;
...
pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;
```

Ensure 32-bit pointers (use 32 bit programming environment, for 64-bit OS and gcc one can use `-m32` if 32-bit support installed).

Comment: Whatever I do I must not change this line -- `pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;` Could this be possible?

Comment: Use first approash with `(&ptemp)` but declare `ptemp` as `uint32_t` and be sure that `sizeof (void*) == sizeof(uint32_t)` (use 32 bit system)

Answer (score 0):

From part of your reply to my comment:

**"I should be able to call Testing_pOP_Start() using pPointerToFunc"**

I assume, you are trying to achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Testing_pOP_Start(void)
{
    printf("Inside");
    return;
}

typedef void (*C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS)(void);
C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS pPointerToFunc= &Testing_pOP_Start;

int main(void)
{
     // your code goes here

    pPointerToFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Try this code and let me know so that i can add more details or otherwise.

Comment: not only this, I should also retain this line -- `pPointerToFunc = (void *)*(uint32_t *)C_FLASH_FUNCTION_ADDRESS;`

Comment: @MSharathHegde Well, in that case you can follow Serge Ballesta's solution, that works. But to me this one does the job in a much cleaner way than what you are trying.